# What does the value on the subtraction of one double pointer from another double pointer signifies?

Tags: c

```
int i = 9;
int *j = &i;
int* l = j + 1; 
int **a=&j;
int **b=&l;
printf("%u\n",a);
printf("%u\n",b);
printf("%d\n",a-b);
```

Output:6422208
6422204
1.
What is 1 indicating to?

Comment: note, while printing a pointer, use `%p` and cast the argument to `void*`

Comment: And to print the type `ptrdiff_t` (which is the type of the result of pointer subtraction) use `%td`. See e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: And IIRC it's only allowed to subtract pointers if they both point to the same "array", that the pointers are really "related". Since `&j` and `&l` aren't "related" you can't really subtract them and expect a sensible result.

Answer (score 1):

`a` contains the adress of the variable `j` (which contains itself the adress of variable `i`)

`b` is the adress of `l`.

Then the first two `printf` show you the adresses where variables `j` and `l` have been allocated to.

In your example `j` and `l` are contiguous in memory (I assume `int` is 32 bits on your architecture). It is just by luck, they could have been located far away from each other.

Finally, when you substract 2 pointers as in the last `printf`, you are doing arithmetic on pointers.

Incrementing a pointer adds to the adress the length of the type pointed to. For example if you print the values of variables `j` and `l` (not their adresses) you would find a difference of 4 between both adresses.

Similarly, the substraction of both adresses equals `4` which represent a difference of `1` in terms of pointer arithmetic for 32 bits architecture. That's why it prints the value `1`.

However keep in mind that pointer arithmetic can be tricky. About substraction the C99 Standard states that:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
> same array object, or one past the last element of the array object

So here I think you are allowed to substract `a` and `b` but this is not something you want to do in a real code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unclean in many ways, see the comments. With that code doing experiments like the one you try to do will not give reliable results.

However lets assume that you have used appropriate code to output the difference of two addresses of pointers to int, of two variable `int* j; int* l;`.

`&j` is the address of the variable `j`, you can store it in a `int** a;`, same for `int** b=&l;`.

The value of the difference `a-b` now is only the difference of the addresses.
For that address difference, this line of your code is irrelevant. `int* l = j + 1;`, it only affects the value of what is pointed to by `&l`, i.e. not the address `&l`.

The value 1 cannot be explained reliably, because there is some freedom of implementation involved. But in many cases, this `int *j; int *l;` will result in `j` ending up immediatly "after" `l` in memory, i.e. at the next highest address. Because of pointer arithmetic this result in `&j == (&l)+1`. At this point the value of 1 for `&j-&l` is obvious.

Comment: "But in many cases, this int *j; int *l; will result in j ending up immediatly "after" l in memory, i.e. at the next highest address". Worth adding it is due to the fact variables are put on the stack in most cases and the stack is "descending".

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I am not sure that all of the shown code is inside a function, because it is not really a MRE. Also the standard does not define what a stack is. I tried to phrase around those (very plausible) assumptions and am happier without making them.

Comment: You're entirely right.  Should have written "it might due to the fact..."

Comment: In my experience the order is also observed for most non-stack (e.g. global) variables. @GuillaumePetitjean

Comment: I don't agree. If they were global variables, `l` would typically be located after `j` in memory , and not before. Or in other words, located in the same order than declaration. of course as you pointed out, it depends on many things, compiler, architecture, ABI, etc...

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I might remember incorrectly (or remember weird edge cases). Thanks for pointing out. I will keep in mind and verify/falsify my memory. Luckily I phrased carefully.